# accessing 2d numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of labels and numpy arrays like below. I want to measure the distance between the arrays only using the euclidean distance.

```
    ('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.]))
    ('blue', array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.]))
```

I will use something like `dist = numpy.linalg.norm(arrayVec1-ArrayVec2)`

How can I specify only the array parts([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.])) and array([ 0.,  0.,  0., ...,  0.,  0.,  1.])) excluding the labels red and blue for the euclidean distance measure?

Comment: Looks like you have 2 tuples, each with 2 items, a string and an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
x= ('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]))
y= ('blue', array([ 0.,  0.,  0., 0.,  0.,  1.]))

np.linalg.norm(x[1]-y[1])
```

Note.

```
print x[1]
```

gives:

```
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
```

Comment: the thing is that when I print out x[1] or y[1] I get

('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]))

and when I run np.linalg.norm(x[1]-y[1]) I get as an error 
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Comment: Probably I am not correct saying that this is a 2d array. Maybe it's not since when I print x[1] it does not print out [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.] but ('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]))

Comment: nope. It prints out 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#77>", line 1, in <module>
    data = np.linalg.norm(data[1]-data[1])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Comment: What version of Python?

Comment: I have got python 2.7.6

Comment: hmm. same as me. You did copy the line `x= ('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]))` ?

Comment: oh yes..it worked. I forgot to copy the line 
x= ('red', array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.])). I did not know that you should put it into another array